# Tantra prayogas

Tags: tantra, chinnamasta

I read somewhere that Chinnamasta Prayogas are so powerful that they can even counteract and nullify powerful prayogas of Dhumavati and Griddhakarni. Is it true and could you share some more info that u may have on the topic?

Comment: It is not completely true. Becuase, Dhumavati when used in highest possible glory can crush any prayoga. Same when Bhaglamukhi if used, can freeze even Dashmahavidyas. Same way Kali in highest glory can not just destroy prayoga but may even kill the sadhaka who dared to harm. Thus, every Mahavidya prayoga is equally potent. Just the person who is doing it, must be scholar. Coz, Mahavidyas if used against one another can be explosive...

Comment: Thank you so much 

Comment: @Chamundadas what does prayoga mean in tantra ? is like like upasana or worship or prayoga like experiment ?

Comment: prayogas in general means use of mantras and tantrik paddhatis for mundane goals like pacifying diseases, shatkarmas such as marana and ucchatana , to get rid of enemies etc. The standard "magic" if u will